# How to replace in stream using Gulp?

Tags: node.js, stream, gruntjs, gulp, build-tools

I try to switch from Grunt to Gulp and I have an issue:

I read two streams from two files

```
var fileStream = gulp.src(file);
var injectionStream = gulp.src(injection)
.pipe(replace('#class-name#', argv.cname));
```

If my console argument "--remove" is absent I have no problem to concatenate these streams

```
.pipe(concat('animation.styl'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
```

However when '--remove' is true I want to delete injection, in other words, subtract injectionStream from fileStream.

I tried:

```
var es = require('event-stream');
es.replace()

var replace = require('gulp-replace');
```

It works with strings, but I cannot succeed with streams read from files. Can anybody give me a small hint?

And maybe it is an incorrect tool for generation task and I should stay with Grunt and\or other tools like yo,etc?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nice work :) Looks like [gulp-replace](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace) might be an easier way for folk coming here from google..

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src(['file.txt'])
    .pipe(replace(/foo(.{3})/g, '$1foo'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/file.txt'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution!

```
fs.readFile(injectionFile, 'utf8', function (err, injStr) {
injStr = injStr.replace(/svv/g, cname);

fileStream
.pipe(gulpif(rm!=true,injectString.append(injStr),replace(injStr,'')))
.pipe(concat(initialFile))
.pipe(gulp.dest(animation))
```

...

It took a while, but I AM HAPPY it's over.

Thank you

Comment: gulp is not as easy to use as it should be :)

Comment: Thank you, Alex. Will take a look.

Comment: from what I have discovered in my brief foray into Node streams - the stream API for Gulp is different than the stream API for Node core, which is really annoying.