# Gulp task to duplicate file, then find & replace string (regex)

Tags: regex, gulp

I'm relatively new to Gulp and looking to create a task that would clone a file, move it to a directory, then find and replace the following (keep note that the number of spaces proceeding the `default!` is different)

```
$primary-color: #000         !default;
$secondary-color: #000                         !default;
$trinary-color: #000   !default;
```

After the Gulp taks, would look like this, keeping the semicolon:

```
$primary-color: #000;
$secondary-color: #000;
$trinary-color: #000;
```

Guessing I'll need to use Gulp replace, doing the following:

```
gulp.task('variables', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/frontend/global/_variables.scss')
             .pipe(replace(REGEX_HERE, ''))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scss/application/global/_variables.scss'));
});
```

but don't know the regex I'll need to remove both `!default` and the preceeding spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace in stream using Gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938283/how-to-replace-in-stream-using-gulp)

Comment: Do you know the regex for what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`gulp-replace`](https://npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) and the regex [`/\s*!default/g`](https://regex101.com/r/0N9iE4/1) you can do it like this:

```
gulp.task('variables', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/frontend/global/_variables.scss')
    .pipe(replace(/\s*!default/g, ''))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scss/application/global/'));
});
```